# Python socket connection error: OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor

Tags: python, sockets

I am trying to write a client/server program in python that will accept multiple connections and manage them using threading.  The server and client both run, and the client will receive the "welcome" message from the servers "processClient" function, which means the connection is being made and the thread is being started.  However, any subsequent receive or send on the connection object after the welcome message fails with an "OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor" error.  I've done some searching on the error, and most problems seem to result from someone trying to use a socket or connection that's been previously closed-which should not be the case here.  Does anyone know what could be causing the error?  Running python version 3.5.2

Server code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3


import socket
import sys
import os
import datetime
import threading
import random

PORT = 65432        # Port to listen on (non-privileged ports are > 1023)

def processClient(conn, id):
        welcome = "Hello, you are client number " +  str(id)
        welcome = bytes(welcome, 'utf-8')
        conn.sendall(welcome)
        while True:
                data = conn.recv(1024)
                print(rpr(data))
                time = str(datetime.datetime.now())
                arr = bytes(time, 'utf-8')
                if data == b'time':
                        conn.sendall(arr)
                elif data == b'':
                        conn.close()
                        return
                else:
                        temp = data.decode("utf-8")
                        temp = temp.upper()
                        temp = bytes(temp, 'utf-8')
                        conn.sendall(temp)

try:
         s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

except:
        print("unable to create socket connection, shutting down.")
        quit()


s.bind(('0.0.0.0', PORT))
s.listen()
sys.stdout.write("Server is running \n")

runningThreads = []
threadID = 0
while True:
        conn, addr = s.accept()

        with conn:
                #conn.setblocking(False)
                print('Connected by', addr)
                threadID += 1
                threadTemp = threading.Thread(target = processClient, args=(conn, threadID))
                threadTemp.start()
                runningThreads.append(threadTemp)
        for t in runningThreads:
                if not t.isAlive():
                        # get results from thtead
                        t.handled = True
                        threadID -= 1
                else:
                        t.handled = False
        runningThreads = [t for t in runningThreads if not t.handled]
```

Client code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import socket
import sys
import os
import datetime
HOST = 0

while HOST == 0 or HOST == "":
        HOST = input("Please enter host IP: ")


PORT = 65432        # The port used by the server

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
        s.connect((HOST, PORT))
        data = s.recv(1024)
        print(repr(data))
        while True:
                inputString = input("Please input a string: ")
                temp = bytes(inputString, 'utf-8')
                s.sendall(temp)
                if inputString == "":
                        quit()

                data = s.recv(1024)
                if data:
                        print(rpr(data))
```

Comment: Looks like you always need to type "time" in the terminal to keep the connection going, or it terminates on any other input. Is that what you are sending to test this?

Answer (score 0):

for anyone else who stumbles across this:  I did finally work out the problem.  The server was not waiting on input from the client before it attempts to read data from the connection, which was triggering the error (the error message was particularly unhelpful in diagnosing this issue).  I rewrote this to use python selectors rather than threads-selectors includes very handy polling functionality that can be used to "pause" until there is data to be read.  I could have built this into the program myself, but why do so when there's already a language feature that does it for you?